# how to wrap each input and label in one div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code and i want to enclose each enclose each input and label with div

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
    <label div="checkbox3">checkbox3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
    <label for="checkbox4">checkbox4</label>
</div>
```

and, i want to enclose each input and label with div like

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
    <label div="checkbox3">checkbox3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
    <label for="checkbox4">checkbox4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to this? What is the problem with the current code you have?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: actually, i can't explain my problem but i want each input and label in div using jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="testing"/>');
});
```

```css
.testing {
  background-color: blue;
}

.testing>label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
  <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
  <label div="checkbox3">checkbox3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
  <label for="checkbox4">checkbox4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @shadow fiend.. it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`

```
$('input').map(function(index){
  $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('input').map(function(index){
  $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
    <label div="checkbox3">checkbox3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
    <label for="checkbox4">checkbox4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Associate both `input` and `label` with [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and select both of the specific elements and [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) them up:

```
$('input').map(function() {
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltwbymxw/3/)

Updated with `.addBack()` since `.addSelf()` is deprecated

Comment: andSelf() has been removed in jQuery 3.0; use .addBack() instead, which should work identically.